# How can I use the final URI segment as an argument without losing the entry variable?

Tags: craft3, templating, routes

I have a Structure - `Products` - that contains multiple products, and each product contains different sub pages (details, pricing, etc).

One section of the Structure is `Details` which is under each product.

The url structure is `/products/{product}/details` where `{product}` is the various products in the Structure.

`Details` entry has an Entries field in it called `Details` that contains entries from a Channel that I'm essentially using as a data silo called `Product Details` that stores details about the various products.

This all works fine and if I load an entry at `/products/x-product/details` I have access to the Details associated with the Details entry as expected.

As part of this particular template, I want to be able to have a fourth segment like:

`/products/x-product/details/specific-detail` -- where `specific-detail` is the slug of a specific channel detail

I've setup a route like so in `config/routes.php`:

`'products/<entrySlug:{slug}>/details/<detailSlug>' => ['template' => 'products/_types/details']`

And it loads the the `details` template fine...however... the `details` template extends a main layout that is used across the entire site, and that layout uses the `entry` variable which it is saying doesn't exist.

I need the `Details` entry var from the Structure to load as the `entry`, and for the final route (`detailSlug`) to be passed through unchanged/ignored to the `details` template so that I can just grab it via `craft.app.request.getSegment()` function and process/use it accordingly inside the template.

I could obviously do this with a url param, but I want to be able to do it with an actual segment for various reasons (one being SEO).

**UPDATE:** OK, so I think I'm getting close -- I can maybe reset the "entry" variable to the Details entry -- but is there a way to grab a specific child of an entry in a Structure if all I have is the slug of the Parent? So like `set entry = craft.entries.section('products').slug("product-x").child("details")` ?

I know that specifc query won't work...but is there something like that? Consider the structure looks like:

```
Products
- Product 1
  -- Details
  -- Pricing
  -- etc
- Product 2
  -- Details
  -- Pricing
  -- etc
```

**UPDATE 2:** I've figured out a way to grab the specific entry I need and reset the entry var -- but some of the fields are null -- I did a `dd` on it, and I can see it's the correct object (correct ID and all) -- but my matrix field and entries fields are null. My other custom fields (text fields) are there and have the correct info in them.

This is the queries I ended up with:

```
{% set parentProduct = craft.entries.section('products').level(2).slug(productSegment).one() %}
{% set entry = craft.entries.section('products').level(3).descendantOf(parentProduct).slug("details").one() %}
```

Comment: Noting re: `null` values when dumping an Entry object—this is the expected behavior, and not a consequence of your approach. I believe it's just a limitation of the Query classes (the initial value for Relation and Matrix fields) and how PHP represents them as strings when debugging. Calling `entry.flexibleContent.all()`, will get the data you're looking for!

Comment: Also worth noting that you can do a generic sort of "protection" routine in your layout so that when `entry` is not defined on a particular template (like the 404 page), it will just exit silently—this could be at output time (`<meta name="description" content="{{ entry.shortDescription ?? 'My default description!' }}">`), or guarding an entire block of output (`{% if entry is defined %} ... {% endif %}`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is REAL ugly I think...and perhaps there's a better way to do it, but this is what I ended up with. Again, I've only been working with craft for a few weeks, so please tell me if there is a better way.

```php
{% set productSegment = craft.app.request.getSegment(2) %}
{% set productDetailSegment = craft.app.request.getSegment(4)  %}

{% if productDetailSegment is not null %}
    {% set parentProduct = craft.entries.section('products').level(2).slug(productSegment).one() %}
    {% set entry = craft.entries.section('products').level(3).descendantOf(parentProduct).slug("details").with(['flexibleContent','productDetails']).one() %}
{% endif %}
```

The `with` function was the key to getting my missing Matrix and Entries fields.

This successfully resets my `entry` var so that it exists in the correct context.

Again, if there's a better way to do this with routing (as I said initially -- someway of ignoring the final segment without losing the entry var -- PLEASE point me in the right direction, because this seems really kludgy).